# Footer doesn't center when I apply 'margin: auto'

Tags: html, margin, center, footer

I've tried this and the footer doesn't center. I tried to put display: block or inline-block but that doesn't serve me either.

HTML:

```html
<div id="secondfooter">
   <p>COPYRIGHT 2020 HYUNDAI AUTO ROMANIA. TOATE DREPTURILE REZERVATE.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#secondfooter {

    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #c00000;
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/bogdan9/o14p39ek/

Comment: It is centered in jfiddle, confused.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing float left, it should work:

```css
#secondfooter {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #c00000;
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

I removed it and it looks  working to me.

Comment: Width needs to be 100%

Comment: I added the width of the body tag of 900px and it worked. Actually the code is just a part of a entire site and I didn't put it here because it was a lot of coding and the problem small. Thank you anyway, I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox and width: 100%. No matter what screen are you on, it will be in center.

```css
#secondfooter {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #c00000;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
  
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
```

```html
<div id="secondfooter">
            <p>COPYRIGHT 2020 HYUNDAI AUTO ROMANIA. TOATE DREPTURILE REZERVATE.</p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give `width: 100%` to `#secondfooter`

```
#secondfooter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #c00000;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```